# How may I burn srt subtitles to video with avconv?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv

System : Xubuntu 13.04 x64

I've found usage of this functionality in ffmpeg [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo)

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt out.avi
```

but it doesn't work. I get an error

```
No such filter: 'subtitles'
```

on that. Same thing happens if I replace `ffmpeg` by `avconv`.

So I tried downloading the `libav` source [here](https://libav.org/download.html) and compile. Again I'm frustrated when I run

```
./configure --enable-libass
```

in the source directory, and this time I got

```
Unknown option "--enable-libass"
```

I wonder if this is a very particular thing that `avconv` doesn't support at all. And

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/869248/hardcoding-subs-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 7):

## Why `subtitles` filter is missing

Libav tends to ignore features from FFmpeg, so `avconv` and their counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" (removed as of 14.04) do not support libass, and therefore does not support the [`subtitles` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) among many other filters.

---

## How to fix

You have several options to get the real `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg:

- [Download a `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) - The easiest option.
- [Compile](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) - Allows full customization.
- [Use mc3man's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) - For 14.04 users
- Upgrade your Ubuntu - FFmpeg returned in 15.04

---

## Usage

### Hardsubs

This will "burn" the subtitles into the video, but of course requires that the video be re-encoded:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt -codec:a copy output.mkv
```

- Filters require re-encoding. See the [FFmpeg H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for encoding suggestions.
- Since you probably do not want to re-encode the audio this example just [stream copies](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-muxes) it.

### Softsubs

Consists of a susbtitle stream that is muxed into the file. Any player worth using will allow you to turn the subtitles on and off and choose from other subtitle streams that may be present. Does not require any re-encoding.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i subtitle.srt -codec copy -map 0 output.mkv
```

Answer (score 5):

`ffmpeg` is not exactly the same as `avconv`. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/648465/burn-in-subtitles-with-avconv) about burning subtitles with `avconv`.

There is another option, easier and with GUI: **Avidemux**. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install avidemux
```

Open a video file, then go to `Video`, choose a video encoder (anything else than `Copy`), `Filters` and `Subtitles`. Choose the `Subtitler` filter:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for introducing that tool to me. But I still need a CLI approach (I need to merge videos on a server).

Comment: @neuront I just found this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1155877